# Android Studio / Случайный размер View в dp

Tags: java, android, view, случайные-числа

Недавно начал заниматься в **Android Studio**. Постоянно обращаюсь для решения вопросов на этот ресурс. Однако сейчас ответа на свой вопрос я не нашел.

Задача: задать случайный размер высоты `view` элемента в приложении.

Проблема: случайное значение применяется в элементе как `px`, а необходимо задать как `dp`.

Код приложен ниже:

---

```
private int x, y, z;

 View1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.View1);

 View2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.View2);

 View3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.View3);

 SecureRandom random1 = new SecureRandom();
 x = random1.nextInt(39) + 1;

 SecureRandom random2 = new SecureRandom();
 y = random2.nextInt(39) + 1;

 SecureRandom random3 = new SecureRandom();
 z = random3.nextInt(39) + 1;

 View1.setHeight(x * 10);

 View2.setHeight(y * 10);

 View3.setHeight(z * 10);
```

....

Comment: Так и гуглите "how convert dp to px android"

Comment: @ЯковЗайцев: А размер текста увеличить интересно не решит ваш вопрос? И если не решит размер текста в ваших TextView должен быть постоянным? Возможно рандомом менять размер текста это то, что вам нужно.

Comment: Большое Вам спасибо!

Comment: @ЯковЗайцев: если ответ вам помог, можно отметить его как правильный.

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте так:

```
Random mRand = new Random();
//вывод случайного значение между мин и макс (Java)
private   int getRandomInt(int min, int max){
    return mRand.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
}


public int dpToPx(int dp) {
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    return Math.round(dp * (displayMetrics.xdpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT));     
}


View1.setHeight(dpToPx(getRandomInt(10,20)) * 10);
```

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17410076/5330439) - dpToPx(int dp){...}

Comment: Большое Вам спасибо!

Comment: @ЯковЗайцев: пожалуйста.

Comment: в diaplaymetrics есть переменная density